# Facebook integration error in php

Tags: php, facebook

I am using facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev. and i have created new app at developer.facebook.

Site URL: http://localhost:80/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/firstPage.php.

I am getting this error at login:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting this error on your dev machine only - it probably doesn't like the hostname localhost.

You may be able to fake the domain name (for dev purposes, within your own machine) using a hosts file entry.  Find your hosts file (depends on you OS) and you can add an alias to your localhost, e.g.

```
127.0.0.1 myapp.example.com
```

Then if you try to access http://myapp.example.com/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/firstPage.php from your the same machine, it will resolve to 127.0.0.1, which is the same as localhost.

Comment: u mean to say i have to use site url like this :http://127.0.0.1:80/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/firstPage.php

Comment: no - in my updated example, it assumes you registered your app with facebook, such that it ran under your domain example.com (or myapp.example.com), so facebook will probably only let you test on a url that starts example.com/....

Comment: can u suggest me some steps for this. that is which URL i have to enter for " SiteURL  and Valid OAuth redirect URIs "so that i can test it on my localhost at port 80. thanks in advance for ur help.

Comment: As I am from iOS, in that case i have to give only Bundle ID and it works perfect. But in PHP i am not getting the issue...